# openshift post_deploy action hook does not working

Tags: git, openshift

I'm new to open shift, and i'm trying to make the `post_deploy` action hook to work. I already created the `post_deploy` file, then i tried

```
git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/* (not working)
```

And

```
git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/post_deploy (worked)
```

But, when I `git push`, I get this error:

```
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure
remote: Activation status: failure
remote: Activation failed for the following gears:
remote: [my_id] (Error activating gear: No such file or directory - /var/lib/openshift/[my_id]/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/action_hooks/post_deploy
```

Any help?

Comment: Hmm maybe try ssh'ing in and see what's up? Try `rhc ssh [your-app-name]`, then `cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR` and check through your directory contents. If things look off, try re-deploying or re-starting.

Comment: The post_deploy exists in server (at the same location shown in the error). I did restart, modified post_deploy file and git pushed again, but i got the same error.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in another application: at first, i forgot to give permissions, so i got: "The .openshift/action_hooks/post_deploy hook is not executable". Then, i did run "git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/post_deploy", commited and pushed again and i got it again: "No such file or directory..."

Comment: @luciddreamz, any new idea?

Comment: Problem solved. I did run post_deploy on server and i saw the real error message: "bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"
It's because i created the file on windows in windows format, so i did save in unix format and it did work. I sent a email to OpenShift suggesting them to investigate how to show real message errors during deploy, because, in that case, the deploy message said post_deploy file does not exist.